# From log-normal parameters, to normal parameters

Tags: normal-distribution, density-function, lognormal-distribution

from the following log-normal fitting function (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html), I get the parameters [s, loc and scale]. How can I use them to get the μ and σ of the corresponding normal distribution? The location parameter troubles me a bit.

Answer (score 2):

What you have there is a *three parameter* lognormal (shifted lognormal). As a result, just taking the log of this is not normal unless "loc" is set to zero.

This three parameter lognormal has the following density:

$$f_{X}(x)={\frac {1}{x}}\cdot {\frac {1}{\sigma {\sqrt {2\pi \,}}}}\exp \left(-{\frac {[\ln (x-\gamma)-\mu ]^{2}}{2\sigma ^{2}}}\right),\:x>\gamma,\,\sigma>0,\,-\infty<\mu,\gamma<\infty$$

The shift parameter $\gamma$ is what that help refers to as the parameter `loc`.

The variable $Y=\ln (X-\gamma)$ is $\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

That is, the log of `scale` is the mean of the log of the back-shifted variate ($X-\gamma$) (i.e. $\mu$ in the above formula, where $\mu=\ln(\text{scale}$)), and `s` is the standard deviation of the log of the back-shifted variate (i.e. $\sigma$ in the above formula).